# Qt QProcess desn't work with arguments containing wildcard charecters

Tags: qt, qprocess

I want to pass an argument containing asterisk to QProcess.  The
code listed below can reproduce my problem:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-l" << "*.cpp";
    QProcess ps;
    ps.start("ls", arguments);
    ps.waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << ps.readAll();
}
```

I can't get `ls -l *.cpp` run as in a shell. What is the right way to make wildcard characters work for QProcess? I'm using Qt 5.15.2 coming with Debian stable.

Comment: `QProcess` goes to some lengths to avoid invoking any shell.  If you want shell globbing try `ps.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "ls -l *.cpp")` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `ls -l *.cpp`, the expansion of `*` to  a list of filenames is performed by your shell.
In this case, `ls` already receives a list of filenames.

In the case of `QProcess`, the process is directly executed without a shell. So there is no party involved that performs the expansion (called "globbing").

In your case, I would use [`QDir::entryList()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) to obtain the list of files and then pass the result as arguments.

Untested example code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QStringList arguments = {"-l"};

    QDir directory("."); // same as QDir()
    QStringList filters = {"*.cpp"};
    arguments << directory.entryList(filters);

    QProcess ps;
    ps.start("ls", arguments);
    ps.waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << ps.readAll();
}
```